# Loop through all .txt files in directory, find a particular value, and calculate total of all values from .txt files

Tags: bash

I'm on a Mac and in a given directory I have 466 .txt files. Within the files, somewhere appears this line:

```
Host2 Total size: 1443504 bytes (1.377 MiB)
```

That line could be anywhere in the file.

If that line doesn't appear, then this one does

```
[LOGIN]: 2 NO LOGIN Failed - Invalid username or password.
```

I need to loop through all of those files and calculate the grand total of bytes. I also need to create a list of the file names that logged a NO LOGIN error.

I know that I probably need read and grep, but this is out of my CLI depth. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify.  What parts of these patterns are constant?  E.g. is it always Host2, or is this a hostname that can be different in each file / line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the bytes in the 4th field and sum using `awk`: (thanks [@mark-setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell))

```
awk '/^Host2 +Total +size: +[0-9]+ bytes / { sum += $4 } END { print sum+0 }' *.txt
```

You could get the list of files that contain "NO LOGIN Failed" using `grep`:

```
grep -lF 'NO LOGIN Failed' *.txt
```

I used somewhat lazy patterns.
If you see false positives,
make them more strict.
For example the last `grep` could match the line exactly with:

```
grep -lFx '[LOGIN]: 2 NO LOGIN Failed - Invalid username or password.' *.txt
```

Comment: @brianrhea I added an example of making the `sed` + `awk` more strict

Comment: What's the point of `sed`? Why not do `awk '/^Host2 Total/{sum+=$4}' *.txt`

Comment: A tiny, tiny tip (learnt from @EdMorton)... if you use `print sum+0` instead of `print sum` it will still work if `sum` has never been assigned, i.e. if no lines matched.